# How to define implication in terms of linear inequality of boolean variables

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, logic, linear-programming

Define the following two groups of linear inequalities: 
$$
P: 
\begin{cases}
   a_1 . x \leq b_1 \\ 
   a_2 . x \leq b_2 
\end{cases}
$$

$$
Q: 
\begin{cases}
   a_3 . x \leq b_3 \\ 
   a_4 . x \leq b_4 
\end{cases}
$$
for some binary vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ (target variables) and coefficients $a_1, b_1, ...$.

We want to simulate the constraints that corresponds to implication $P \rightarrow Q$, i.e. $Q$ should hold, only $P$ holds true (for some $x$).

My (bad) solution, which used linear programming (i.e. linear inequalities, plus extra linear objective): 
Introduce an auxiliary binary variable, create the news constraint set:

$$
W: 
\begin{cases}
   a_1 . x \leq b_1.y + (1-y).\text{bigNumber} \\ 
   a_2 . x \leq b_2.y + (1-y).\text{bigNumber} \\
   a_3 . x \leq b_3.y + (1-y).\text{bigNumber} \\ 
   a_4 . x \leq b_4.y + (1-y).\text{bigNumber}
\end{cases}
$$
and add $y$ to the linear objective with some small positive coefficient (assuming that we are doing maximization), so that it always $y = 1$ over $y=0$. The bad thing about this solution is that it requires using objective. I wonder if there is a way to bypass this.

Comment: So $P$ does not necessarily hold? And if it does, then $Q$ should too, otherwise it should not?

Comment: @Kuifje true. $P$ does not necessarily hold.

Comment: And do you want $P$ to hold preferably? Because the solver will most likely always choose to not consider it if it can, to solve a less constrained problem with a better solution.